# JavaFX: Reset object with bound members

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I have an object with bound members in JavaFX andI want to reset the members to initial state at a certain moment.

So my first option is to reset them one by one, which is to much code, but its works fine.

The other option is to re-instantiate i.e. `myModel = new Model()`, but in the case the object reference changes and I lose my binding.

Is there any alternative way to accomplish this?

***EDIT***

*Model*

```
public class Service extends BaseModel {
    private StringProperty serviceType = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> buyingPrice = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new BigDecimal(0));
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> sellingPrice = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new BigDecimal(0));

    public Service(){

    }

    public String getServiceType() {
        return bundle.getString("service");
    }

    public StringProperty serviceTypeProperty() {
        return serviceType;
    }

    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType.set(serviceType);
    }

    public BigDecimal getBuyingPrice() {
        return buyingPrice.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> buyingPriceProperty() {
        return buyingPrice;
    }

    public void setBuyingPrice(BigDecimal buyingPrice) {
        this.buyingPrice.set(buyingPrice);
    }

    public BigDecimal getSellingPrice() {
        return sellingPrice.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> sellingPriceProperty() {
        return sellingPrice;
    }

    public void setSellingPrice(BigDecimal sellingPrice) {
        this.sellingPrice.set(sellingPrice);
    }
}
```

The bindings:

```
public class ServiceForm extends HBox implements Initializable {
    private Service service = new Service();

    @FXML
    private TextField serviceDescriptionField;

    @FXML
    private TextField servicePriceField;

    @FXML
    private Button addButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        serviceDescriptionField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(service.descriptionProperty());

        servicePriceField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(service.sellingPriceProperty(), new BigDecimalStringConverter());
    }

    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Button getAddButton() {
        return addButton;
    }

    public void setAddButton(Button addButton) {
        this.addButton = addButton;
    }
}
```

Doing this does not clear my fields and I believe it breaks my binding:

```
serviceForm.setService(new Service());
```

Comment: With "reset them one by one" do you mean you set the values of properties that are the members of your object are bound to to have an initial value? Or it is a biderictional binding? Show us some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to have the `Service` as a property:

```
private ObjectProperty<Service> service = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Service());
```

Extract the bindings into a private method which is able to unbind old bindings and create new ones:

```
private void createBindings(Service oldService) {
    // Unbind if there is an older service
    if (oldService != null) {
        servicePriceField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldService.sellingPriceProperty());
        serviceDescriptionField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldService.descriptionProperty());
    }

    servicePriceField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(service.get().sellingPriceProperty(), new BigDecimalStringConverter());
    serviceDescriptionField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(service.descriptionProperty());
}
```

and then in the `initialize` method:

```
createBindings(null);
service.addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> createBindings(oldval));
```

This way if you call `service.set(new Service())`, the bindings will be created for the new `Service` and will be removed for the previous one.

Now when you add new bindings, you can bundle them in the `createBindings` method while adding the unbinging logic to the same place. Note: this could be further generalized.

Comment: Generalized meaning `createBinding` could be rendered generic?

Comment: No. I meant to somehow encapsulate this logic into an abstract controller that has the `createBindings` abstract method and also the model property, and automatically creates the listener for the model property and calls this method. Then the subclasses (e.g. your `ServiceForm`) could subclass this class and could only implement the `createBindings` method. I meant something like this.